# Recovery by MQTT client for MQTT server failure/restart

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, paho

I have a long-running paho-MQTT (Python 3) client.  The client is listen-only - it subscribes to topics and acts on those inputs but it does not publish.  Everything runs fine until the server becomes unresponsive (server restart or network transport failure); at that point it becomes unresponsive since the connection is broken.  The subscribes are all QOS=0.

What mechanism exists to alert the client that the server is inop?  Do I need to manually check for stale input or is there a call-back or exception that will get thrown?  If stale input is detected, what's the best practice for recovery to re-establish the subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the Paho Python [docs](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#on-disconnect)

> **on_disconnect()**
>
> `on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc)`
>
> Called when the client disconnects from the broker.
>
> - client, the client instance for this callback
> - userdata, the private user data as set in Client() or user_data_set()
> - rc, the disconnection result
>
> The rc parameter indicates the disconnection state. If
> MQTT_ERR_SUCCESS (0), the callback was called in response to a
> disconnect() call. If any other value the disconnection was
> unexpected, such as might be caused by a network error.
>
> On Disconnect Example
>
> ```
> def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
>     if rc != 0:
>         print("Unexpected disconnection.")
>
> mqttc.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
> ```

Comment: I have an on_disconnect callback defined, but it never gets triggered.  On clients that publish, I do get a disconnect.  As a point of note, for this application I am using mqttc.loop(2.0) instead of starting a separate thread with mqttc.loop_start().  Would that make a difference?

Comment: How long have you left it? it should get triggered after the 1.5 times the keepalive period.

Comment: keepalive is set to 240 since the connection is over a potentially slow network.  It has frequently been over an hour and occasionally overnight before the stagnant connection was detected.  Its difficult to put a timer on the client end since the messages are asynchronous and it may be hours between messages.  I could add a heartbeat message, but I'd rather keep net traffic low.

Comment: After putting in some additional logging, it appears the connection does get recovered - without triggering the on_disconnect.  What appears to happen is the subscription gets dropped.  But I need some trigger that this has happened so I can recover.